# C Reverse words in string

Tags: c, string, reverse, words

Trying to learn C and so I want to reverse each word in string. 
"Hello World" to "olleH dlroW"
This is what I have so far.

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i;
    printf("Enter string:");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            // Here the space and how should I switch words now?
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Should I do something like this:

**temp = str[i];
j = str[i-1];**

and then switch places? **str[i]=j; and j=temp;**
I am stuck at this point here!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble writing program to reverse words in string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243374/having-trouble-writing-program-to-reverse-words-in-string-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't give away the answer because this seems like a homework problem and is a great opportunity to learn, but here is a hint:

Think about how you could programatically reference the 'opposite' of each letter in the word. So str[0] and str[strlen(str)], and so on. That should help you, but feel free to probe with further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string targetWords = "Hello World";
    int count = targetWords.Length;
    string result = null;
    string chr = null;

    while (!(count == 0)) {
        chr = targetWords.Substring((count - 1), 1);
        result += chr;
        count -= 1;
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(result);

}
```

Comment: Is this in `C language`?